# aspnet web api how to validate using modelstate in multipart form data?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data, modelstate

I am new for using asp net web api.
I want to create UploadDocument feature in my web api.
so, I create this way.

From Client

```
api.post('vendor/UploadDocument', formData, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } })
```

Controller

```
public class VendorController : ApiController {
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage UploadDocument()
    {
        try
        {
           if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
           throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);

           var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
           var model = new UploadDocumentViewModel();
           model.field1 = request.Form["field1"];
           model.field2 = request.Form["field2"];
           model.Document = request.Files["Document"];

           if (ModelState.IsValid)
           {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
           }
           else //ModelState is not valid
           {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
           }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
           return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
public class UploadDocumentViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string field1 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int field2 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public HttpPostedFile Document { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is, in controller ModelState always empty.
I have tried to add code

```
Validate(model);
if (ModelState.IsValid)...
```

but it didn't work too.
can someone have any idea for validating model data annotation in multipart form data ?

Comment: Your POST method dos not contain a model so there is nothing to validate. Make your method `UploadDocument(UploadDocumentViewModel model)` and it will be bound with the posted values (as a side note, an `int` cannot be `null` - its required by default so your `[Required]` attribute is unnecessary unless your wanted a specific error message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try clear model state before validate

```
ModelState.Clear(); 
this.Validate(model); 
if (ModelState.IsValid) {

}
```

Check this answer : [Custom DataAnnotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39608083/custom-dataannotation-isvalid-not-called/39608988#39608988)

Comment: you are welcome :) please approval to answer for other people to benefit

Answer (score 0):

Your method should look like this:

```
public class VendorController : ApiController {

      [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult UploadDocument(UploadDocumentViewModel viewModel)
        {
            try
            {
               if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);

               if (viewNodel == null)
                   return BadRequest("Model is empty");

               var field1 = viewModel.field1;
               var field2 = viewModel.field2;
               var documents = viewModel.document;

               if (ModelState.IsValid)
               {
                    return Ok();
               }
               else
               {
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
               }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
               return InternalServerError(exception);
            }
        }
    }
```

I prefer to passing some of those validations in action filters, to make your methods cleaner (try/catch, modelstate).

If you will have some problems with model binding, you can implement your custom model binder.

Comment: hi Merchezatter, I tried you solution but get an error from the browser said
: 415 (Unsupported Media Type), I post the data using multipart/form-data, not json.

Comment: Looks like your controller have another opinion, about data type you passing. What type does your "formData" have? Is that MultipartFormDataContent ?

Comment: that post may be helpful to you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772792/httprequest-content-ismimemultipartcontent-is-returning-false-when-it-should-r)

Comment: hi Merchezatter, thank for your reply. My "formData" is using javascript FormData.. the code is like this.
let formData = new FormData(); 
formData.append("field1", "field1_value"); 
formData.append("field2", "field2_value"); 
formData.append("Document", selectedFile);